# How to use a photo editor in ionic framework

Tags: ionic-framework, photoeditorsdk

I downloaded a photo editor application based on [photoeditorsdk](https://www.photoeditorsdk.com/documentation/html5/getting-started), but it has built in J query and HTML 5. If I integrated it, How may I do it ? Or IONIC-1 is compatible with any other editor ? Please suggest me what should I do.

Or what photo editor is suitable for ionic-1....?

Comment: Mind providing link to sdk or library you're using ?

Comment: I was trying to integrate the photoeditorsdk. The link is https://www.photoeditorsdk.com/documentation/html5/getting-started. but I could not manage it. If you have knowledge about other photo editor, please share with me.

Comment: are you using react.js ? SDK seems to be using that too.

Comment: No, I didn't. I downloaded this apps but it built on Jquery mobile and html. But I want to use same editor for hybrid application (obviously by using ionic-1).

Comment: Check these : https://github.com/CreativeSDK/phonegap-plugin-csdk-image-editor#prerequisites , https://developers.aviary.com/

Comment: Thanks. I am using it. even I registered and generated in adobe but what I will do after that....?

Comment: check this sample https://github.com/imgly/pesdk-ionic-demo